# Rails 5 jquery file upload image orientation rotated 90 degrees for portraits

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, jquery-file-upload

I'm having trouble with the image orientation after uploading an image to my s3 account. Portrait images are rotated 90 degrees when images are displayed. Here is the coffee script I am using from the [Heroku - Direct to S3 Image Uploads in Rails](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails) tutorial.

```
# Use this instead of jQuery -> with Turbo links. Turbo links will trigger the ready page:load.
document.addEventListener 'turbolinks:load', ->

  $('.directUpload').find('input:file').each (i, elem) ->
    fileInput = $(elem)
    form = $(fileInput.parents('form:first'))
    submitButton = form.find('input[type="submit"]')
    progressBar = $('<div class=\'bar\'></div>')
    barContainer = $('<div class=\'progress\'></div>').append(progressBar)
    fileInput.after barContainer
    fileInput.fileupload
      fileInput: fileInput
      url: form.data('url')
      type: 'POST'
      autoUpload: true
      formData: form.data('form-data')
      paramName: 'file'
      dataType: 'XML'
      replaceFileInput: false
      progressall: (e, data) ->
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        progressBar.css 'width', progress + '%'
        return
      start: (e) ->
        submitButton.prop 'disabled', true
        progressBar.css('background', 'green').css('display', 'block').css('width', '0%').text 'Loading...'
        return
      done: (e, data) ->
        submitButton.prop 'disabled', false
        progressBar.text 'Uploading done'
        # extract key and generate URL from response
        key = $(data.jqXHR.responseXML).find('Key').text()
        url = '//' + form.data('host') + '/' + key
        # create hidden field
        input = $('<input />',
          type: 'hidden'
          name: fileInput.attr('name')
          value: url)
        form.append input
        return
      fail: (e, data) ->
        submitButton.prop 'disabled', false
        progressBar.css('background', 'red').text 'Failed'
        return
    return
  return
```

---

I'm using an image_tag to display the image from my S3 account.

```
= image_tag current_company.logo.image_url
```

---

I'm not sure what I need to do to fix the orientation. I did find this in the [blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#imageorientation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#imageorientation), but have no clue if this is what I am looking for or how to use it if it is. Any help would be appreciated.

---

This is my first time posting on here so please be gentle.